# How to kill stack activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Please tell me any one, how to kill previous stacked activity.My requirement is like that
 let I move from activity 
    A---->B----->C------>D----->E
 Then activity stack will be   **E-D-C-B-A** 
 Now I am at **E** if my all work is done  then I move to activity **B**
 using

```
startActivity(intent); 

this.finish();
```

this code will be kill only  **E** activity but I want to kill **C D** activity also.
how can I do that.
thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to call Activity [B] with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
Intent b = new Intent(this,B.class);
b.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(b);
this.finish();
```

This will kill `C D E`

Comment: Will it create new instance of Activity B or will just bring the old one to the front ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller go through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, B.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass activity context into intet so that you can call finish on the activity.

also goo idea would be to start the activities by using `startActivityForResult(Intent, int).`

Where `int` is code for the activity you are starting.

later you can call `finishActivity(int requestCode)` which will kill the activity for the code you provided. You can have codes (id's) for activities in your `strings.XML`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)